# Problem with lambda i always get invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Im currently watching a tutorial on Youtube ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYV81L7qd6M&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-lB8MZfHPLTEHO9zJDDLpYj&index=4)) for making a UI for my application and i receive this error and im not able to fix it.

The code:

```
self.a_Build_Info.triggered.connect.(lambda: self.clicked("Build was clicked"))
self.a_Credits.triggered.connect.(lambda: self.clicked("Credits was clicked"))
self.a_Discord.triggered.connect.(lambda: self.clicked("Discord was clicked"))
self.a_Exit.triggered.connect.(lambda: self.clicked("Exit was clicked"))
```

The Error:

```
self.a_Build_Info.triggered.connect.(lambda parameter_list: expression))
                                    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Remove those dots `.` before `(lambda...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks accdias,

The problem was a simple dot. Thanks again for your feedback

**Problem Solved.**